# design deduplication sql statement using NULLS vs MAX VALUE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to sculpt a SQL statement to de-dupicate a table.

The table has three keys: key1, key2, key3 used as a business key.
A date is also being used.

The rules are (assuming matches in key1, key2, key3):

```
If all rows have dates, retain only MAX(date)
If one row has a date, and others are NULL, retain only row with date
If all rows has date = NULL, keep all rows.
```

I've been using this code as a basis:

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT [key1], [key2], [key3], [date],
       RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY [key1], [key2], [key3], [date] ORDER BY [date] desc)
   FROM dbo.Table1
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

I am not educated on how to apply the rules on sql statement.  Any wisdom would be greatly appreciated.

Example deduplications:

```
CASE 1: before dedupication:            
key1    key2    key3    date
1   A   1   null
1   A   1   null
1   A   1   null

after deduplication:            
key1    key2    key3    date
1   A   1   null
1   A   1   null
1   A   1   null

CASE 2: before dedupication:            
key1    key2    key3    date
1   A   1   1/1/2016
1   A   1   1/1/2016
1   A   1   1/1/2016

after deduplication:            
key1    key2    key3    date
1   A   1   1/1/2016

CASE 3: before dedupication:            
key1    key2    key3    date
1   A   1   1/1/2016
1   A   1   1/2/2016
1   A   1   1/3/2016

after deduplication:            
key1    key2    key3    date
1   A   1   1/3/2016

CASE 4: before deduplication            
1   A   1   1/1/2016
1   A   1   1/1/2016
1   A   1   null

after deduplication:            
key1    key2    key3    date
1   A   1   1/1/2016


CASE 5: before deduplication            
1   A   1   1/1/2016
1   A   1   1/2/2016
1   A   1   null

after deduplication:            
key1    key2    key3    date
1   A   1   1/2/2016
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to me.  Can you include sample data and what you want to happen?

Comment: @arcee123, your conditions don't cover "If a few rows have a date, and other rows have NULLs".

Comment: @Anton, thanks. the row with max(date) prevails of all records in that scenerio.

Comment: can be the case when there are multiple rows for same combination of key1, key2, key3 and date columns?

Comment: only when all rows have date=NULL, otherwise dedup occurs.

Comment: I don't get it. What is 'dedup occurs'? When? Before running your query? So you have two dedup processes? We don't know your data, your table structure, so pay more attention to description if you don't provide it. I'll ask again - can we have same non-null Date for Key1,Key2,Key3?

Comment: I added examples of deduplications (dedup) that I am trying to find.  if any keys are different, there is no dedup operation to be had.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there, I believe, just need a WHERE to exclude rows satisfying rule #3 from deletion.

```
 ;WITH CTE AS(
        SELECT [key1], [key2], [key3], [date],
           RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY [key1], [key2], [key3] ORDER BY isnull([date], '19000101' desc)
        FROM dbo.Table1 t1
        WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * 
                       FROM dbo.Table1 t2 
                       WHERE t1.key1=t2.key1 
                         and t1.key2=t2.key2 
                         and t1.key3=t2.key3 
                         and t1.[date] IS NOT NULL
                     )
    )
    DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  how does this satisfy CASE 1?

Comment: Sry, partition by business key only, edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT [key1], [key2], [key3], [date],
       RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [key1], [key2], [key3] ORDER BY [date] desc),
       mxD = max([date]) OVER (PARTITION BY [key1], [key2], [key3])
   FROM dbo.Table1
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1 and mxD is not null
```